# Análise de dados com lista em python

Tags: python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista em txt com os seguintes dados:

**lista.txt**

```
AC;12;733559;8476515;11.57
AL;27;3120494;24574808;7.87
AM;13;3483985;59779292;17.17
AP;16;669526;8265965;12.36
BA;29;14016906;154340458;11.01
CE;23;8452381;77865415;9.22
DF;53;2570160;149906319;58.49
ES;32;3514952;82121834;23.38
GO;52;6003788;97575930;16.25
MA;21;6574789;45255942;6.89
MG;31;19597330;351380905;17.93
MS;50;2449024;43514207;17.77
MT;51;3035122;59599990;19.64
PA;15;7581051;77847597;10.26
PB;25;3766528;31947059;8.48
PE;26;8796448;95186714;10.82
PI;22;3110292;22060161;7.07
PR;41;10444526;217289677;20.81
RJ;33;15989929;407122794;25.46
RN;24;3168027;32338895;10.21
RO;11;1562409;23560644;15.10
RR;14;450479;6340601;14.05
RS;43;10693929;252482597;23.61
SC;42;6248436;152482338;24.40
SE;28;2068017;23932155;11.57
SP;35;41262199;1247595927;30.24
TO;17;1383445;17240135;12.46
```

Onde cada coluna funciona, respectivamente: **UF,CODIGO, POPULACAO,PIB,PIBPERCAPITA**

Ao ler esse arquivo, eu preciso fazer com que o programa me retorne um menu com funções como:

- Ver os dados uma UF específica
- mostrar os dados de algumas UF especificadas
- Ou mostrar estatísticas como (média, valor mínimo e valor máximo)

Só que eu não sei pra onde vai, como fazer a leitura de uma coluna.
Não sei qual seria a função em python.
Se alguém puder me dar um caminho já é muita ajuda.

Eu tenho o meu código desse jeito:

```
#enconding utf-8

import os
import platform

plataforma = platform.system()

if (plataforma == "Windows"):
    os.system("cls")
else:
    os.system("clear")

arquivo = open("C:\python\lista.txt", "r")
texto = arquivo.read()

dados = []
with open("C:/python/lista.txt") as lista:
    for linha in lista:
        if(linha.strip() != ''):
            coluna = [i.strip() for i in linha.split(' ')[:3:3]]
            dados.append(coluna)
print(dados)
```

Eu consigo imprimir mas sai todo bagunçado. Consegui esse código aqui no site.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa do módulo [*pandas*](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Para instalar execute o comando:

```
pip install pandas
```

depois importe:

```
import pandas as pd
```

para fazer a leitura do arquivo, utilize a função [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('lista.txt', delimiter=";",
       names=["UF","CODIGO", "POPULACAO","PIB","PIBPERCAPITA"])
```

se der um `print` terá a seguinte saída:

```
    UF  CODIGO  POPULACAO         PIB  PIBPERCAPITA
0   AC      12     733559     8476515         11.57
1   AL      27    3120494    24574808          7.87
2   AM      13    3483985    59779292         17.17
3   AP      16     669526     8265965         12.36
4   BA      29   14016906   154340458         11.01
5   CE      23    8452381    77865415          9.22
6   DF      53    2570160   149906319         58.49
...
```

#### Código completo:

```
#enconding utf-8
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('lista.txt', delimiter=";",
       names=["UF","CODIGO", "POPULACAO","PIB","PIBPERCAPITA"])
print(df)
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ShadyGrouchyNetworking)

#### Referência:

- [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)
- [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Que massa! Muito mais simples e organizado!

Comment: Ahhhh! Muito show! Vou reproduzir aqui. Com essa sua resposta acredito que consigo fazer a terceira questão que também pede pandas como referência. Obrigado @NoobSaibot.

Comment: Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se preferir a outra resposta, pode marcá-la como correta/aceita, mas apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada dessa forma. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma função simples que faz a leitura do arquivo e retorna uma lista com os dados do estado desejado. Partindo daí você pode fazer cálculos, estátistica, ou o que quiser com os dados.

```
def retornar_informacoes_estado(diretorio_txt, uf):

    try:
        arquivo = open(diretorio_txt, 'r')
        dados_arquivo = arquivo.read()
        arquivo.close()

        dados_arquivo = dados_arquivo.split('\n')

        tamanho_dados = len(dados_arquivo)

        for i in range(tamanho_dados):

            estado = dados_arquivo[i].split(';')

            if(estado[0] == uf):
                return estado

    except:
        return False
```

A função faz a leitura do arquivo e separa cada linha em uma lista.
Depois separa cada dado de um estado em uma lista chamada estado, então verifica se existe algum estado conforme a entrada do parâmetro então retorna essa lista com os dados do estado.

Comment: Enquanto eu não tinha um caminho pra resolver minha questão eu tava imprimindo os resultados por coluna, mas de forma muito errada e tosca, não da forma que eu queria kkkk Segue o print até onde eu consegui fazer: http://prntscr.com/jy2muq

Comment: Filipe, me tira uma dúvida... Aqui `arquivo = open(diretorio_txt, 'r')` em `diretorio_txt`eu coloco o caminho do meu arquivo txt né isso? E em `def retornar_informacoes_estado(diretorio_txt, uf):` eu deixo do jeito que está? Eu tentei colocar em `arquivo = open("c:/trabalho/questao2/lista.txt", "r")` e tentei imprimir todos os dados e não consegui.

Comment: Isso, coloca o diretório do teu arquivo!
Em na função tu ocoloca o endereço e o estado que tu quer ter o retorno!

Comment: Desculpa, Filipe... Eu sou iniciante em python, essas funções eu não sou muito bom em fazê-las e nem tenho uma lógica de programação bem desenvolvida... Eu consigo imprimir de um `def` uma simples soma, como nessa imagem: http://prntscr.com/jy7ydb. Mas eu não estou conseguindo imprimir nesse seu código, não tô conseguindo encontrar a variável nem conseguindo encaixar o print pra imprimir a tabela no console... Se eu conseguir imprimir a tabela no console o resto eu consigo de boas, pq é somente condições. É o que eu sei mais kkkk. Me dá um help nessa parte?

Comment: Nessa parte "dados_arquivo = dados_arquivo.split('\n')" tu tem todos os teus valores em matrizes da seguinte maneira [ [uf, codigo, populacao, pib, pibpercapita], [uf, codigo, populacao, pib, pibpercapita], [uf, codigo, populacao, pib, pibpercapita]].
Tu vai ter cada estado em uma posição dessa matriz

Comment: Mais tarde vou editar a resposta e vou tentar explicar melhor cada passo que fiz!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79252/discussion-between-sandson-costa-and-filipe-santos).